# Cannot get CORS to work with contenType - Django Rest Framework

Tags: jquery, django, backbone.js, django-rest-framework, django-cors-headers

I have been wasting the whole day on this stupid little issue!

I'm using `django-rest-framework` for my api and backbone.js in the front end.

I cannot do any request to the server when adding the option `contentType`.

Here is a simple example of what I'm trying to do:

```
$.ajax
    url:"http://127.0.0.1:8080/foo/"
    type:"POST"
    data: '{"e":"e"}'
    contentType: "application/json"
```

The OPTIONS fails and the POST is never sent.

The options request headers:

```
Access-Control-Request-Headers:accept, origin, content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method:POST
Origin:http://localhost:8000
```

Now I don't know why the OPTIONS fail. I'm using the corsheaders app for django, and the settings are as follows:

```
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = (
    'x-requested-with',
    'content-type',
    'accept',
    'origin',
    'authorization'
)
```

Comment: Can you share the OPTIONS response headers?

Comment: Also, do you need a `CORS_ALLOW_METHODS` attribute? e.g. CORS_ALLOW_METHODS = (
        'GET',
        'POST',
        'PUT',
        'PATCH',
        'DELETE',
        'OPTIONS'
    )

Comment: The OPTIONS response is completely empty in Chrome

Comment: Do you mean CORS_ALLOW_METHODS = ( 'GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE', 'OPTIONS' )  in settings.py?  that does not help

Comment: in my views: @api_view(['POST', 'GET','DELETE','OPTIONS']) they are allowed.

Comment: The OPTIONS response will be empty, you will have to look at the response headers to see if any CORS-specific headers are there.

Comment: I figured out that there is nothing wrong with cors. But rather with my computer. The same code works on others computers, just not mine. It must be some software that is doing this. I have no idea what. Cant do anythign

Answer (score 3):

```
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
```

is enough if you have the following setup correctly

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    *
    'corsheaders',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    *
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
)
```